# Possible mode error

Tags: c, mode, calculation

I've made this program that computes the mean, the median and the mode from an array. Although I've tested with some examples, I found out there might be a case that I have forgotten as for many of the inputs I've tested it works but the testing program that my teacher is using gave me an error for a certain test, but I was not presented with its input. Maybe someone can have a look and see if I am making a mistake at the mode point of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *array = safeMalloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int value;
        scanf("%d", &value);
        array[i] = value;
    }

    //mean
    double mean;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + (double)array[i];
    }
    mean = sum / n;
    printf("mean: %.2f\n", mean);

    //median

    float temp;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    printf("median: %d\n", array[n / 2]);

    //mode

    int val = array[0], noOfRepetitions = 1, valMax = array[0], maxRepetitions = 1, possibleMax = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            noOfRepetitions++;
        }

        if (array[i] != val) {
            val = array[i];
            noOfRepetitions = 1;
        }

        if (noOfRepetitions == possibleMax) {
            maxRepetitions = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (noOfRepetitions > maxRepetitions) {
            valMax = val;
            maxRepetitions = noOfRepetitions;
            possibleMax = maxRepetitions;
        }
    }

    if (maxRepetitions > 1) {
        printf("mode: %d\n", valMax);
    } else {
        printf("mode: NONE\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My idea for mode was because the numbers are sorted when just transverse it. If the next element is the same as the previous one, increase the `noOfRepetitions`. If the `noOfRepetition` is bigger than the `maxRepetitions` until now, replace with that. Also store the last maximum val needed if we have for example more than 2 numbers with the same number of repetitions.

EDIT: The mode of an array should return the number with the maximum number of occurrences in the array.If we have 2 or more number with the same number of maximum occurrences , there isn't a mode on that array.

Comment: Please note that, from a statistical point of view, when 2 or more numbers have the same maximum occurrences you have a multimodal distribution, rather then no mode at all.

Comment: How about an _unsorted_ input? If your array is `1 2 1 5 1 4 1 3 3 1`, will your program return `1` or `3` as a mode? Will it find a median?

Comment: Also, for the median, in case of even number of elements, you should take the average of the two central values.

Comment: @Bob__ Actually _any_ number between the middle two will do as a median, not necessarily their arithmetic mean.

Comment: @CiaPan OP sorts the array (without qsort) before calculating the median. Yes, you are right about the median.

Comment: @Bob__ Right, I didn't notice that part of code.

Comment: @CiaPan I sorted the array before I put it through mode operation.As for the case when I have an even median I don't have a problem as I will only have even number of values as an input.

Comment: `void *safeMalloc(int n)` Should be `void *safeMalloc(size_t  n)`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no purpose for the variable `possibleMax`. You should just remove these lines:

```
    if(noOfRepetitions==possibleMax){
        maxRepetitions=1;
        continue;
    }
```

They cause `maxRepetitions` to be reset erroneously.

You could detect if the distribution is multimodal and print all mode values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, i;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;
    int *array = safeMalloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    //mean
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + (double)array[i];
    }
    printf("mean: %.2f\n", sum / n);

    //median

    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("median: %d\n", array[n / 2]);

    //mode

    int val = array[0], noOfRepetitions = 1, valMax = array[0], maxRepetitions = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            noOfRepetitions++;
            if (noOfRepetitions > maxRepetitions) {
                valMax = val;
                maxRepetitions = noOfRepetitions;
            }
        } else {
            val = array[i];
            noOfRepetitions = 1;
        }
    }

    if (maxRepetitions == 1) {
        printf("mode: NONE\n");
    } else {
        printf("mode: %d", valMax);
        val = array[0];
        noOfRepetitions = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (array[i] == val) {
                noOfRepetitions++;
            } else {
                if (noOfRepetition == maxRepetitions && val != valMax) {
                    printf(", %d", val);
                }
                val = array[i];
                noOfRepetitions = 1;
            }
        }
        if (noOfRepetition == maxRepetitions && val != valMax) {
            printf(", %d", val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not in my mind. The idea of possibleMax was in fact for the case when I have multiple numbers with the same maximum frequency. For example if I delete that line the case 1 1 2 2 3 will give me mode=2 when it should give me none as both 1 and 2 have frequency 2. I then reset the maxRepetition to 1 as I later consider that if the maxRepetition doesn't change and remains to 1 to print none.

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify what you mean by *mode*?

Comment: @AndreiMădălinOancă: if the distribution is multimodal, ie has multiple values that appear the same maximum number of times, you might want to print them all, but your approach with `possibleMax` is not sufficient to achieve that. You could instead keep track of the number of values that have the maximum number of occurrences and print that along with the mode.  I updated the code for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered my mistake. I didn't think of the case when I have numbers with same maximum frequency and after that came one with lower frequency but still bigger than others. For example : 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 6.With my code , the result would have been 3 . I just needed to change the comparison of noOfRepetitions with oldMaxRepetition.

Comment: ` oldMaxRepetition` is not defined. It is unclear what change you made to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to search a mode seems too complicated.  Compare this:

```
    //mode

    int val = array[0], noOfRepetitions = 1,
        valMax = array[0], maxRepetitions = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            if (++noOfRepetitions > maxRepetitions) {
                valMax = val;
                maxRepetitions = noOfRepetitions;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            val = array[i];
            noOfRepetitions = 1;
        }
    }
```

It's probably the simplest code to do what you need, but it overwrites `maxVal` and `maxRepetitions` much too often.

The following version overwrites the two 'max' variables only once per each new maximum found – at the cost of duplicating some part of code:

```
    //mode

    int val = array[0], noOfRepetitions = 1,
        valMax = array[0], maxRepetitions = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            ++noOfRepetitions;
        }
        else
        {
            if (noOfRepetitions > maxRepetitions) {
                valMax = val;
                maxRepetitions = noOfRepetitions;
            }

            val = array[i];
            noOfRepetitions = 1;
        }
    }

    if (noOfRepetitions > maxRepetitions) {
        valMax = val;
        maxRepetitions = noOfRepetitions;
    }
```